# problemas agregando clases al hacer petición ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy haciendo un código que me permita recorrer imágenes haciendo una petición Ajax. Es decir, veo una imagen a la vez vez, ya que recibo los datos como array y los voy mostrando uno por uno con la función each, agregando una clase por cada dato. Finalmente con javascript paso una imagen a la vez, viéndolas como slideshow. Hasta acá todo bien pero necesito actualizar el DOM, limpiándolo cada vez que realizo una petición Ajax. He intentado con el método .empty pero por alguna razón no me permite realizar el código.
Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

page1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.gallery').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var data = this.dataset;

            $.ajax({
                url: "page2.php",
                data: data,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    var imgs = data.map(function(img) {
                        return '<img src="'+img+'" height=200px>';
                    });
                    $.each (imgs, function(i,val) {
                        $('.container').append('<div class="imagen numero' + i + '"></div>');
                        $('.imagen.numero' + i).html(val);
                    })
                    $.getScript("slides.js");
                } 
            });
        });
        })
    </script>  
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam felis mi, pellentesque at scelerisque eu, consectetur quis felis. Aliquam mollis</p>
    </div>

    <a class="gallery" href="page2.php" data-var="dir/1/">
        GALERIA 1
    </a><br>  

    <a class="gallery" href="page2.php" data-var="dir/2/">
        GALERIA 2
    </a>  

    <div class="container">
        <a class="prev" onclick="passSlides(-1)">❮</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="passSlides(1)">❯</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

page2.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$directorio = $_POST['var'];
echo json_encode (glob($directorio . '*.jpg'));
?>
```

slides.js

```
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function passSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('imagen');
        if (n > slides.length) {
            slideIndex = 1
        }    
        if (n < 1) {
            slideIndex = slides.length
        }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    }
```

Comment: Gracias Eduen Sarceño y Marcos Gallardo. Ambas soluciones funcionan.

Answer (score 2):

Para borrar solo los elementos `<div class="imagen">` dentro de `<div class="container">` puedes usar [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Así por ejemplo:

```
...
$(".container").find('.imagen').remove();
$.each (imgs, function(i,val) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

No puedo comentarte, así que publicaré e iré editando la respuesta para ampliar más

> Necesito actualizar el DOM, limpiándolo cada vez que realizo una petición Ajax.

No creo que necesitas limpiar todo el DOM, basta limpiar el contenido del contenedor, el único inconveniento de hacer `$(container).html(null)` es que perderías los controles del slider, así que la solución más sencilla es cambiar esta parte del código.

Para el **html** en *page1*

```
<body>
    ...
    <div class="container">
        <div></div>
        <a class="prev" onclick="passSlides(-1)">❮</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="passSlides(1)">❯</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

En el **Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gallery').click(function (event) {
        var data = this.dataset;
        var container_div = $('.container div');

        container_div.html(null); // limpia las imagenes 

        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function(data) {
                ...
                $.each (imgs, function(i,val) {
                    container_div.append('<div class="imagen numero' + i + '"></div>');
                    $('.imagen.numero' + i).html(val);
                });
                ...
            } 
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
})
```

Lo única función del `<div>` creado anteriormente es para salvaguardar el contenido dinámico, así si se sobre escribe directamente sobre él, no afectará otras áreas (como es el caso de los controles del slider.)